# How to limit node.js bandwidth?

Tags: node.js, bandwidth

Is it possible to limit bandwidth for a certain node.js process? It appears that `pause`/`resume` on socket data doesn't actually affect the download speed.

I've also tried trickle to no avail: `trickle -d 1 -u 1 node band.js`, shows the same speed as without trickle.

Comment: [Limiting network throughput of an already launched process](http://serverfault.com/questions/217080/limiting-network-throughput-of-an-already-launched-process-linux-freebsd)

Comment: I'm going to agree with @Mustafa that you probably want to do this with an os-level utility as opposed to with code in your node.js program. Try asking on superuser about why you can't get trickle to work. That seems like a solid approach to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem on this. I posted a issue on github project libuv, it's the core of event system of Node.js, since I believe that's the cause why trickle does not work. (https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/844)

Thanks to response from bnoordhuis, the reason trickle can't work is because of libuv use system_call to use system call directly, not by calling glibc. However, trickle only wrap glibc functions to add bandwidth limitation support.

I haven't found a perfect solution yet, but you can try these:

1. pfSense: a freebsd-based standalone firewall with bandwidth limitation support
2. netbrake: like trickle, worked with Node.js, but it's not accurate, and need to limit upload and download bandwidth together
3. trickle: if you are trying to do some experiments, you can try to use trickle on the client side, since trickle is worked with curl